# Hide codeigniter both controller and method name from url

Tags: php, codeigniter

My url was like this: `http://example.com/controller/method/param1/param2/param3/param4`

My goal is: `http://example.com/param1/param2/param3/param4`

Here my controllers 'Home' and 'Read'. I also include my view and route configuration at bottom.

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /*
    *   Index method
    */
    public function index() {

        $this->db->select('a.*, c.*');
        $this->db->join('category as c', 'c.catid=a.catid');
        $this->db->limit(10);
        $this->db->order_by('a.id', 'DESC');

        $data['query'] = $this->db->get('article as a');

        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }

}


<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Read extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        /*
        *   Index method
        */
        public function index() {

            $id = isset($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : FALSE;

            $this->db->select('a.*, c.*');
            $this->db->join('category as c', 'c.catid=a.catid');
            $this->db->where('p.id', $id);
            $this->db->limit(1);

            $data['query'] = $this->db->get('article as a');

            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('single_view', $data);
            $this->load->view('footer');
        }

    }
```

home_view.php

Please take a look at anchor below, that was my goal to produce `http://example.com/param1/param2/param3/param4`

```
<div class="post-content">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach( $query->result() as $post ) : ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url($post->term_name.'/'.$post->term_id.'/'.$post->id.'/'.strtolower(url_title($post->title))); ?>"><?php echo $post->title ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I defined the controller name, it's no problem. But I can't figure out how my url for single post only contain those four params

```
<?php echo site_url('read/'.$post->term_name.'/'.$post->term_id.'/'.$post->id.'/'.strtolower(url_title($post->title))); ?>
```

Below my route configuration:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "read/index/$1";
```

Any help and advices will be appreciated.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the docs you can place next route:

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'controller/method/$1/$2/$3/$4';
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'controller/method/$1/$2/$3';
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'controller/method/$1/$2';
```

or if you are passing numbers/integers

```
$route['(:num)/(:num)/(:num)/(:num)'] = 'controller/method/$1/$2/$3/$4';
```

You mustn't forget to pass arguments to your method as well, even as FALSE.

```
public function index($param1, $param2, $param3, $param4)
{
    //rest of code that is using params
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Tpojka, your solution works great. Now I'm struggling with 404 redirect occured when I remove/delete one of those params from url

Comment: Edited. Be aware of wildcard placeholder to be after known routes. If answer is valid, you can accept it to make it searchable from engines. [Docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom `routes` in `config/routes.php`. For-Example

```
    #http://example.com/controller_name/method_name/param1/param2/param3/param4

        $route['param1/param2/param3/param4'] = 'controller_name/method_name';

       #Instead of -> 
#http://example.com/controller_name/method_name/param1/param2/param3/param4
      # Display -> http://example.com/param1/param2/param3/param4
```

Comment: Do you mean `$route['param1/param2/param3/param4']` is similar to `$route['(:any)/(:num)/(:num)/(:any)']` according to my goal?