# How to set URL without displaying controller and function name

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, url-rewriting, url-routing

I want to display this URL,

http://localhost/cosmetics2/index.php/Services/index

without displaying the controller name and the function name...
so how to do that can u please tell me to how to fix this...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide codeigniter both controller and method name from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186185/hide-codeigniter-both-controller-and-method-name-from-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use routes for that, In your `application/config/routes.php`.

See the example,

`$route['route_name_you want_to_Show']  = 'Services/index';`

[Reference](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

And if you want remove index.php then add below code into .htaccess

htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ci/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Comment: how do i call the route in the href link ?? Thank you

Comment: i already mentioned in line one that where you have to define `route`

Comment: no i mean how do i call the route in href link ...
<li> <a href="IN_HERE">services</a> </li>

Comment: okay...in that place you can write the name which you write in `$route['route_name_you_want_to_show']`. So in your where you want to use route, you can write the same name you use. ` <li><a href="route_name_you_want_to_show">services</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit route to your `route.php` file, You can find it in `application/config/route.php`. 
After add line like `$route['mycustomurl'] = 'Services/index'`; and your url is like `http://localhost/index.php/mycustomurl`.
For more details about codeigniter route don't hesitate to read the documentation https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html.

> if you want to remove `index.php` 
>   This would help [CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)